# How to extract out a specific field from structured string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm now trying to extract the text from a structured string by regex.
For instance,

```
string = "field1:afield3:bfield2:cfield3:d"
```

all I want is the values of field3 which are 'b' and 'd'

I try to use the regex = `"(field1:.*?)?(field2:.*?)?field3:"`

and split the raw string by it.

but I ve got this:

```
['', 'field1:a', None, 'b', None, 'field2:c', 'd']
```

So, what is the solution?

The real case is:

```
string = "1st sentence---------------------- Forwarded by Michelle 
Cash/HOU/ECT on ---------------------------Ava Syon@ENRON To: Michelle 
Cash/HOU/ECT@ECTcc: Twanda Sweet/HOU/ECT@ECT Subject: 2nd sentence---------
------------- Forwarded by Michelle Cash/HOU/ECT on -----------------------
----Ava Syon@ENRON To: Michelle Cash/HOU/ECT@ECTcc: Twanda 
Sweet/HOU/ECT@ECT Subject: 3rd sentence"
```

(one line string, without \n)

a list

```
re = ["1st sentence","2nd sentence","3rd sentence"]
```

is the result needed

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe just use `re.findall(r'field3:([a-z])', s)`? Or are the `b` and `d` just placeholders? Then use `re.findall(r'field3:(.*?)(?=field\d|$)', s)`.

Comment: 'b' and 'd' could be a sentence or more

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Thank you! your regex works well. But the real case is that the string is "1st sentence---------------------- Forwarded by Michelle Cash/HOU/ECT on  ---------------------------Ava Syon@ENRON To: Michelle Cash/HOU/ECT@ECTcc: Twanda Sweet/HOU/ECT@ECT Subject: 2nd sentence---------------------- Forwarded by Michelle Cash/HOU/ECT on  ---------------------------Ava Syon@ENRON To: Michelle Cash/HOU/ECT@ECTcc: Twanda Sweet/HOU/ECT@ECT Subject: 3rd sentence"

Comment: The '1st sentence','2nd sentence','3rd sentence' are the text i need actually

Comment: I am on a mobile now. Please update the question with the new data so as formatting is rendered correctly. As I noticed, use `re.DOTALL` if your data spans across multiple lines.

Comment: Updated the new data.

Comment: Something like `(?:^| Subject:)(.*?)(?:Forwarded by |$)` I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
re.findall(r'field3:(.*?)(?=field\d+:|$)', s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h8Te1J/2). NOTE: `re.findall` returns the contents of the capturing group, thus, you do not need a lookbehind in the pattern, a capturing group will do.

The regex matches:

- `field3:` -  a literal char sequence
- `(.*?)`  - any 0+ chars other than line break (if you use `re.DOTALL` modifier, the dot will match a newline, too)
- `(?=field\d+:|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires (but does not consume, does not add to the match or capture) the presence of `field`, 1+ digits, `:` or the end of string after the current position.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/RwIZ71):

```
import re
rx = r"field3:(.*?)(?=field\d+:|$)"
s = "field1:afield3:b and morefield2:cfield3:d and here"
res = re.findall(rx, s)
print(res)
# => ['b and more', 'd and here']
```

NOTE: A more efficient (unrolled) version of the same regex is

```
field3:([^f]*(?:f(?!ield\d+:)[^f]*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Gojov5/1)

Comment: Good job, as always with your regexen.

Comment: thank you! your regex works well for this example. And i ve updated a real case in the question

Comment: Thank you! Solve it by your regex for the real case!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). It will find any character directly after `field3` :

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "field1:afield3:bfield2:cfield3:d"
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=field3:).', string)
['b', 'd']
```

This would only work for a single-character. I would add a positive lookeahead, but it would become the same answer as Wiktor's.

So here's an alternative with `re.split()`:

```
>>> string = "field1:afield3:boatfield2:cfield3:dolphin"
>>> elements = re.split(r'(field\d+:)',string)
>>> [elements[i+1] for i, x in enumerate(elements) if x == 'field3:']
['boat', 'dolphin']
```

Comment: What if 'b' and 'd' are some sentence length unknown?

Comment: Thank you for your patience and the answer！

Answer (score 1):

A complex solution to get *field* values by *field* number using built-in `str.replace()`, `str.split()` and `str.startswith()` functions:

```
def getFieldValues(s, field_number):
    delimited = s.replace('field', '|field')  # setting delimiter between fields
    return [i.split(':')[1] for i in delimited.split('|') if i.startswith('field' + str(field_number))]

s = "field1:a hello-againfield3:b some textfield2:c another textfield3:d and data"

print(getFieldValues(s, 3))
# ['b some text', 'd and data']

print(getFieldValues(s, 1))
# ['a hello-again']

print(getFieldValues(s, 2))
# ['c another text']
```